# limit of $2^n\arcsin\frac{\sqrt{y_0^2-x_0^2}}{2^ny_n}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to know why $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}2^n\arcsin\frac{\sqrt{y_0^2-x_0^2}}{2^ny_n}=\frac{\sqrt{y_0^2-x_0^2}}{y}$ when $y_n\rightarrow y$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Here $y_0$ and $x_0$ are constants. I thought about using a theorem $\lim ab=\lim a\lim b$. Then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}2^n=\infty$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow }\arcsin\frac{\sqrt{y_0^2-x_0^2}}{2^ny_n}=0$. So I think I need a different approach.

Comment: It will probably help to remember that $\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{\arcsin t}{t} = 1$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth That's a real good suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: recall that:
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\arcsin x}{x}=1 $$
Now let $x=\frac{1}{2^n}$, which clearly goes to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. After some algebraic manipulations, you should obtain the given result.